# How to replace values with a condition in R?

Tags: r, vector, replace, conditional-statements

With a vector `dr`, I need to check if there are more than 5 values in `dr > 0`. If so keep it as as. If not return the vector with replacing all values with 0.

```
dr <- c(1,5,3,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0)
```

will be

```
dr <- c(1,5,3,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0)
```

but

```
dr <- c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0)
```

will be

```
dr <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `replace()` to replace the whole vector with zeros if there are less than 5 positive values in it.

```r
fun <- function(vec) replace(vec, sum(vec > 0) < 5, 0)
```

`sum(vec > 0) < 5` returns a single logical value (either `TRUE` or `FALSE`) and it'll recycle to the same length as `vec`.

###### Test

```r
dr1 <- c(1,5,3,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0)
dr2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0)

fun(dr1)
# [1] 1 5 3 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0

fun(dr2)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `replace(vec, length(vec[vec > 0]) < 5, 0)` if you want the amount of values > 0 rather than the sum

Comment: @king_of_limes `sum(vec > 0)` is to count the amount of values > 0. Your code does the same thing as mine.

Comment: True. Guess I misremembered this from a usecase I had some time ago.

Comment: @king_of_limes Maybe an explanation is in order:  `vec>0` will produce a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s. Conveniently in R `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`. So a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s is also a vector of `1` and `0` and thus you can call `sum` on it. It feel hacky but it works like a charm and is often useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if` and `else`:

```r
f <- function(vec) if(sum(vec > 0) >= 5) vec else rep(0, length(vec))
```

Also works with `integer`:

```r
f <- function(vec) if(sum(vec > 0) >= 5) vec else integer(length(vec))
```

---

Operationalization:

```r
> dr <- c(1,5,3,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0)
> f(dr)
#> [1] 1 5 3 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0

> dr <- c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0)
> f(dr)
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
r
 [1] 1 5 3 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0
v
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
vector_0 <- function(ip_vec){
      if(isTRUE(rle(ip_vec)[[2]][which(rle(ip_vec)[[1]] == 5)] == 0)) {ip_vec * 0}
      else {ip_vec}
}
vector_0(r)
 [1] 1 5 3 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0
vector_0(v)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Seems a little bit cumbersome but I'm glad to understand what's the logic

Comment: @Maël, sorry, corrected it